# How to setup Sass and Compass workflow with Server and SVN so every one in team can use and compile sass on server?

Tags: ruby, svn, sass, lamp, compass-sass

We have started to use Sass with Compass for a new project. Currently I'm locally compiling `scss` to `css` and committing generated `css` file to **svn** (installed in test server) only. And because of that only I can work on `Sass` files and I want to give the ability to edit `sass` files to other developers too. and I would also like to setup the workflow in the manner we can work from anywhere, work on `.scss` file and compile (on save/commit) on server. *without having Ruby, Sass gem, compass gem installed on local PC*.

How to install sass, compass, chunky png on LAMP server and How to allow everyone to edit and compile .scss to .css file?

and we are also using SVN for version control.

Comment: Well, you know - your question poorly related to SVN?! And - storing artifacts instead of source in SCM is always bad idea

Answer (score 2):

- **If** scss can be compiled to css in non-interactive mode

and

- **If** compilation tools can be installed on test-server

you can try

1. Save real sources (*.scss) in repository
2. Post-commit hook in addition to current tasks (export of update WC for reflecting changes in repo) will get task of compiling scss

PS: Can't see any problem here - obvious task and obvious (**single!**)solution

Comment: OK I want to compile scss to css on server. Is that possible?

Comment: @JitendraVyas - I have no idea. I even don't know, about which thing you said. I wrote two (common) conditions, it's *your game* now - check their enforceability

Comment: yes, it is possible to compile sass / scss on the server. every rails 3 app does this.